# Bash Script execute more than one command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am new to bash. My issue is, when I run this script it only does the first command and does not finish the rest of them. Is there a way to make bash execute all of these commands from one startup script ?

I have a startup script as follows:

```
#! /bin/bash
cd dockerfiles/nginx
exec docker build -t nginx .
wait
cd ../percona
exec docker build -t percona .
wait
cd ../memcache
exec docker build -t memcache .
wait
cd ../sphinx
exec docker build -t sphinx .
wait
cd ..
exec docker build -t php .
wait
cd ..
exec docker-compose up
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `exec` command tells bash to do the same thing done by the `execve()` syscall -- to **replace its own process table entry** with the program being run.

By nature, this operation means that the script is no longer running when complete. If you don't want that, just take out the `exec` prefixes.

(Also, there's absolutely no reason to use `wait` here at all; `wait` only has any effect whatever if a process is backgrounded, and you aren't backgrounding anything).

---

That said, you might consider using subshells to scope the `cd` operations -- and then `exec` will replace only the subshell's process, not the parent; it's not strictly necessary even in that case, but is a slight performance optimization (likewise, replacing `#!/bin/bash` with `#!/bin/sh` is a performance improvement on platforms providing a lightweight `/bin/sh` since you aren't using any bash-only features):

```
#!/bin/sh
(cd dockerfiles/nginx && exec docker build -t nginx .)
(cd dockerfiles/percona && exec docker build -t percona .)
(cd dockerfiles/memcache && exec docker build -t memcache .)
(cd dockerfiles/sphinx && exec docker build -t sphinx .)
(cd dockerfiles && exec docker build -t php .)
docker-compose up
```

Comment: You might see the edits I added, which let you get rid of all the `cd ..` mess (and actually _do_ make profitable use of `exec`, albeit as a completely optional performance enhancement).

Comment: I do see your edits, and have changed my script to match them. This is far better than what I had. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Also note that this can be simplified with a loop: `for f in nginx percona memcache sphinx; do ( cd dockerfiles/$f && exec docker build -t $f . ) ; done`  This makes it easier for a human reader to see the similarities in the commands.

Comment: @WilliamPursell, indeed; if we didn't have `php` breaking the pattern, I would have suggested that. (Though I'd tend to suggest using quotes on expansions in that code, just by way of demonstrating good practices)